# Вычисления в одной таблице

Tags: sql

```
ticket_id                                               время действия

1           GROUPNAME   Группа 2                        1448083005
1           NAME        Иванов Иван Иванович            1448083501
1           NAME                                        1448083616
1           GROUPNAME   Группа 1                        1448083616
1           NAME        Петров Петр Петрович            1448087763
```

Существует таблица, история изменений тикета. Можно ли 1-им запросом вычесть время из NAME - GROUPNAME

Извините действительно забыл указать что это является результатом выборки:

```
select fieldname,fieldvalue,create_date from table
   where ticket_id= '1' 
and fieldname in('GROUPNAME', 'NAME') and VALUE is not null
order by CREATE_DATE asc



GNAME       Группа 1                                        1447687002
PERSNAME    Иванов Иван Иваныч                              1447690690
GNAME       Группа 3                                        1447690706
PERSNAME    Петров Петр Петрович                            1447691557
GNAME       Группа 6                                        1447691575
PERSNAME    Пупкин Вася                                     1447738078
GNAME       Группа 1                                        1447738227
PERSNAME    Иванов Иван Иваныч                              1447741471
GNAME       Группа 6                                        1447741613
PERSNAME    Пупкин Вася                                     1447741727
GNAME       Группа 7                                        1447741750
PERSNAME    Алексеева Елена Борисовна                       1447742574
PERSNAME    Бредихина Ирина Дмитриевна                      1447761301
GNAME       Группа 2                                        1447761647
PERSNAME    Васильева Ирина Владимировна                    1447762306
```

Comment: можно, если знать как связать между собой groupname и name - джойните таблицу саму к себе по этой связи и вычитаете. На данный момент, по вашему примеру, я, например, не знаю к чему относится "Петров Петр Петрович" - к первой группе или ко второй или сразу ко всем. Когда определитесь с этими неясностями, тогда можно будет сделать все одним запросом

Comment: а по тикет ИД, нельзя с джойнить?

Comment: ну по тикет ИД и придется джойнить, но только когда Вы разберетесь с записями. ВОРОН Вам объяснил... У Вас 5 записей по тикету: две с `GROUPNAME` и три с `NAME`. Ну и как узнать какую из какой вычитать?

Comment: а тут интересный момент) после `GROUPNAME ` обязательно идет `NAME`

Comment: Порядок строк в БД не специфицирован. Поэтому невозможно предсказать, в каком виде выведутся приаведённые вами данные.

Comment: можете попробовать что-то с курсорами придумать

Comment: @Grundy курсор точно так же потребует выборки. а порядок записей в любой выборке непредсказуем, если нет явного order by

Comment: @PashaPash, я думаю приведенная таблица уже является результатом выборки. и по ней вполне возможно можно будет пробежаться

Comment: @Grundy тогда топикастеру стоило бы привести ее в вопросе, и не заставлять остальных гадать :)

Comment: @PashaPash :-D ну это уже другой вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, сам сталкивался с следующим: есть простой запрос `select * from table_name`, в консоли mysql в течение некоторого времени стабильно выводит один порядок записей, через php в течение этого же времени стабильно выводит в другом порядке. Консольный клиент вроде неявно сортировал по id, а php сортировал по дате последнего изменения. Так что, если порядок сортировки не указан явно, то не стоит полагаться на него.

Comment: @BOPOH если это все в одном запросе выполняется - какая разница откуда пришел запрос? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, когда порядок сортировки не гарантирован, можно столкнуться с тем, что локально все работает, а на другом сервере уже нет. Явное лучше неявного, т.к. избавляет от многих проблем

Comment: @BOPOH, но так как мы не знаем каким запросом получилась таблица из поста, мы не можем сказать явно там задана сортировка или нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо воспользоваться пользовательскими переменными.

```
select fieldname, fieldvalue, create_date,
IF(fieldname='NAME', create_date-@d, @d:=create_date)
from table, (SELECT @d:=0) AS z
where ticket_id= '1' 
and fieldname in('GROUPNAME', 'NAME') and VALUE is not null
order by CREATE_DATE asc
```

Я объясню:

- `(SELECT @d:=0)`: объявляем переменную, и задаем ей изначальные параметры. В ней мы будем хранить значение `create_date` последней `GROUPNAME` записи
- `IF(fieldname='NAME', create_date-@d, @d:=create_date)`: если текущая запись это имя пользователя - считаем разницу между текущим `create_date` и последней запомненной датой `GROUPNAME`
  иначе текущая запись, это `GROUPNAME`, значит обновляем содержимое `@d` для дальнейших рассчетов.

Несколько моментов:

- в метках у Вас стоит `sql`. Это как? Описанный выше вариант работает в `mysql`. Если у Вас `mssql` то понадобится другой подход. Там проще будет процедуру написать.
- как Вы понимаете, здесь исключительно важна очередность записей, потому что рассчеты основаны на предыдущих записях... так что аккуратней с `ORDER BY`

Comment: это оракл, чето до сих пор мучаюсь )